# How do I create a batch file to insert text from a .txt to a new txt and repeat the task?

Tags: bind

wow, bad title, but here is what I am looking to do.
Text-file-1 contains:

```
123.com
234.com
567.com
```

I need to have those values inserted into a new document in 2 places, and them move to the next line and insert.

Output file would look like this

```
zone "123.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.123.com";
allow-update { none; };allow-transfer {10.10.10.10; };
};


zone "234.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.234.com";
allow-update { none; };allow-transfer {10.10.10.10; };
};


zone "567.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.567.com";
allow-update { none; };allow-transfer {10.10.10.10; };
};
```

You can see that the domain from the first file is inserted into 2 spots on the result.
I am new to batches and have no idea how to start this.
Any help truly appreciated.

Comment: *nix or Windows? That would change the answers greatly...

Comment: It is not so much a batch file problem as choosing an editor for the job. You can do it in a batch file with `sed`, a Unix program which has been ported several times to Windows, or you can use a regular expression editor, such as medit or Notepad++. Regular expressions will allow you to replace `^.*$` with `{string1}&{string2}&{string3}`, where the first expression matches a whole line, and the `&` in the second expression represents the matched line from the first expression. The precise syntax will depend on your OS and editor.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a `Bash` shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    cat <<RECORD
    zone "${line}" IN {
        type master;
            file "/etc/bind/zones/db.${line}";
        allow-update { none; };allow-transfer {10.10.10.10; };
    };

RECORD
done < Text-file-1
```

And a `Python` version for both `Linux` and `Windows`.

```
text = r"""
zone "%s" IN {
            type master;
                file "/etc/bind/zones/db.%s";
                allow-update { none; };allow-transfer {10.10.10.10; };
                };
"""

lines = [ x.strip() for x in open('Text-file-1').readlines() ]

for line in lines:
    print(text % (line, line))
```

Output:

```
zone "123.com" IN {
            type master;
                file "/etc/bind/zones/db.123.com";
                allow-update { none; };allow-transfer {10.10.10.10; };
                };


zone "234.com" IN {
            type master;
                file "/etc/bind/zones/db.234.com";
                allow-update { none; };allow-transfer {10.10.10.10; };
                };


zone "567.com" IN {
            type master;
                file "/etc/bind/zones/db.567.com";
                allow-update { none; };allow-transfer {10.10.10.10; };
                };
```